# How to enable statusBarItem right away in vscode extensions API

Tags: vscode-extensions

I have some extensions code in `extension.ts`

```
const item = vscode.window.createStatusBarItem(
    vscode.StatusBarAlignment.Right
  );
  item.command = "codevids-auth.pushToWebview";
  item.text = "$(record) codevid";
  item.show();
```

I can't figure out how to place the statusBatItem in automatically without having to fire the command. Is this possible since some plugins as soon as they are installed they show up in the statusbar. I would like to know how to do this.

Thanks for the help ahead of time. And please let me know if you need more details I am happy to explain further.

Comment: Are you using ` "activationEvents": [
  "onStartupFinished"
 ],` ? So that your extension is activated "immediately".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you may not be using an `activationEvent` which would trigger your extension's `activate` function immediately after startup is finished.  Try this:

```js
"activationEvents": [ "onStartupFinished" ]
```

Then your code, which includes `.show()`, should be sufficient to show the `StatusBarItem` soon after vscode is reloaded or started.  It is typical that installation of an extension is not enough to activate it, the user should get a badge on the Extension view that reload is required.  If that is what you are trying to avoid, I don't think it is possible.